# How to reference methods that are using tuples in xml documentation

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

I have a method with the following signature:

```cs
public static float CalculateDistanceBetweenClans(Clan clan1, Clan clan2, List<(ulong owners, float distance, float weight)> settlementOwnersPairedList)
{
    ...
}
```

And I want to reference it from some other method's description:

```cs
/// <remarks>
/// This method could be used to supply
/// <see cref="DistanceMatrix{T}.CalculateDistanceBetweenClans(Clan, Clan, List{(ulong owners, float distance, float weight)})"/>
/// method with required list argument.
/// </remarks>
public static List<(ulong owners, float distance, float weight)> GetSettlementOwnersPairedList(DistanceMatrix<Settlement> settlementDistanceMatrix)
{
    ...
}
```

While this code is handled by the compiler without any exceptions, IntelliCode does not display the result as a method reference. It is shown as a plain text.

Comment: There are two bugs: the first is that this syntax is generated but not accepted (it only accepts the more verbose and less descriptive (`DistanceMatrix{T}.CalculateDistanceBetweenClans(Clan, Clan, List{ValueTuple{ulong, float, float}})`) and the second is that even with a correct reference (like the previous, or just `DistanceMatrix{T}.CalculateDistanceBetweenClans` if there are no overloads) IntelliCode will still not resolve the member as a link. This is a direct result of the tuple members having names: if the names are removed resolving will work correctly.